# Do we have to obey the laws of the bible? If so, what laws?

Tags: biblical-basis, mosaic-law, law-and-gospel

I've read a ton about obedience in the bible and I realize that we have a responsibility to obey Jesus Christ. As it says in 2 Timothy 2:19 "God's foundation stands firm, sealed with his inscription. Anybody that professes the name of Christ must repent of their wickedness"

There's really no way around this. However, when I begin to speak about our responsibility to obey Jesus people begin to tell me that I am trying to follow the law or work for my salvation.

I know that neither of these will earn my way into God's grace, however, I still understand that I have a responsibility.

Where do you draw the line? What do we have to obey and what do we not have to obey?

Comment: There's also "26 Just as the body is dead without breath, so also faith is dead without good works." ~James 2:26

Comment: @El'endia: If a body doesn't breathe, it's a sign of death.  Likewise for faith.  That means that, like a living body will *automatically* (you cannot suffocate yourself by holding your breath) breathe, faith will beget works.  It's not a requirement, it's an effect.  **Very** important distinction.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Always make sure to balance out James 2 with Romans 4, though.

Comment: **This question has Galatians written all over it, especially Galatians 2-4.** If you really want to grasp the purpose of the Law and its applications today, start there. Then you can look at Acts 10; 15; Matthew 5:17-19; Romans 3:31; 7:7-12; Galatians 3:19-24 for a lot more.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's easy to get tripped up trying to figure out what you should or shouldn't do, but I find the below very helpful in getting right to the heart of the matter and really the heart of God.

[**Matthew 22:37-40**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2022:37-40&version=NIV)

> **37** Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’
>
> **38** This is the first and greatest commandment.
>
> **39** And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’
>
> **40** All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.”

Comment: +1 because it's the core of God, Jesus, Holy Spirit and everything... it's 42, if you will ;-)

Comment: @Jürgen: Haha 42! I've never heard that used in a Christian context, but I like it.

Comment: @sty You could also, a little more serious, say that God is 42... he *is* the answer to life, the universe, to... everything.  :D

Comment: How to love God? Love means different things to different people. God's version of how to love is the ten commandments. If you don't keep the commandments then it simply means you don't love. That's why Paul says "Love is the fulfillment of the law". The commandments are still in force, for the Bible says "Blessed are they who keep the commandments of God that they may enter in through the gates into the city.." in the very last chapter of Revelation.

Answer (score 26):

## Yes - but *which of them* is a matter of debate

Since I already did a lot of work to answer [To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply/494#494) I'm going to adapt that answer here, too. Similarly, I'll list and briefly describe some of the more common views along with sources.

### Catholic

The Catholic Church teaches that the Law of Moses (the Old Law) is a *preparation for the Gospel*, and as such no longer binding. The New Law (the Law of Gospel) is a *perfection* of it, given through faith in Christ.

The Law of the Gospel, which applies to Christians, is presented in the **Sermon of the Mount (Matthew 5-7)**, but also in *the moral catechesis of the apostolic teachings*, such as **Romans 12-15, 1 Corinthians 12-13, Colossians 3-4, Ephesians 4-5**, etc.

God's Law has always remained the same, and has always been available as the *natural moral law* (e.g. through conscience), but only Jesus could express it perfectly.

**Source**: Catechism of the Catholic Church, Second edition. Paragraphs 577-582 and 1950-1986. http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/ccc_toc2.htm

### Reformed

The reformed teaching is that the law was given in three parts:

- The moral law, which God gave first to Adam, and later to Moses on Sinai (the Ten Commandments).
- Ceremonial laws, given to the people of Israel, *prefiguring Christ*.
- Judicial laws, given to the State of Israel.

The moral law is eternal, binding Adam, the first man, as well as any Christian today.  Ceremonial laws were abolished in the New Testament. Judicial laws only concerned the State of Israel.

As noted, the moral law was delivered to Moses as the Ten Commandments. Thus the **Ten Commandments** apply to Christians today as such. Of other laws in the OT, the *moral* component applies. Moral laws given in the **New Testament** are also part of the eternal moral law, and meant for Christians of today.

**Source**: Westminster Confession, chapter XIX. http://www.reformed.org/documents/wcf_with_proofs/ch_XIX.html

### Theonomy

*Theonomy* literally means "God's law". It is the notion that God's law is eternal and universally binding. That is, **the entire Bible applies to Christians** today. Every law God has given us is meant to be obeyed.

This doesn't mean that *salvation* comes by keeping the law, as theonomy is often misrepresented. Salvation is granted "solely by grace through faith in the person and work of Jesus Christ".

Psalm 119:97-98 (KJV) is a good verse to show what theonomy is about:

> O how love I thy law! it is my meditation all the day. 
>   Thou through thy commandments hast made me wiser than mine enemies: for they are ever with me.

**Source**: Duncan, T.M. Theonomy: What it is; what it is not. http://www.ipc.faithweb.com/documents/THEONOMY.htm

### Dispensationalism

Dispensationalism makes a distinction between Israel and the Christian church in God's plan. Its major objective is to be able to interpret the Bible consistently literally.

Dispensationalists recognize seven *dispensations* in the Bible:

1. Innocence (Genesis 1:1–3:7)
2. Conscience (Genesis 3:8–8:22)
3. Human government (Genesis 9:1–11:32)
4. Promise (Genesis 12:1–Exodus 19:25)
5. Law (Exodus 20:1–Acts 2:4)
6. Grace (Acts 2:4–Revelation 20:3)
7. The millennial kingdom (Revelation 20:4-6)

The different dispensations are different ways that God has related to people. Salvation has always been through faith.

As today's Christians are living during the dispensation of grace, or during the New Covenant, the old laws or the Old Covenant do not bind them. Because God and His will do not change, the moral law of the New Covenant hasn't notably changed from the Old Covenant.

The Old Testament thus is not for Christians. **Laws expressed in the epistles** are part of the dispensation of grace, and thus apply to Christians. Laws stated by Jesus are not, and thus are not really meant for Christians but for Jews. *(Though I expect there to be a small minority of dispensationalists saying otherwise.)*

**Source**: What is dispensationalism and is it biblical? http://www.gotquestions.org/dispensationalism.html <sup>(I'd like to find a better/more original source)</sup>

Answer (score 13):

What does it mean to "have to" obey God's laws?

I "have to" show up to work, or I will lose my job. I "have to" grow old (I have no choice in the matter).

The binding of God's laws to Christians falls into neither of these categories. It is neither the case the disobedience negates salvation nor that we are unable to sin.

That said, the law is sometimes said to have several "uses" (in different formulations, depending on your background). One formulation has the following:

1. *Civil*, for the restrain of sin among Christians and non-Christians alike.
2. *Pedagogical*, pointing out our sin and bringing us to Christ's grace.
3. *Normative*, showing us how to live our lives.

All of these uses apply to Christians; the law keeps order, shows us Christ's mercy, and guides us to live Christian lives in a God-honoring way.

Answer (score 10):

Paul made the role of the Law of Moses clear in his epistle to the Galatians:

> **19** Wherefore then serveth the law? It was added because of
>   transgressions, till the seed should come to whom the promise was
>   made; and it was ordained by angels in the hand of a mediator.
>
> **20** Now a mediator is not a mediator of one, but God is one.
>
> **21** Is the law then against the promises of God? God forbid:
>   for if there had been a law given which could have given life, verily
>   righteousness should have been by the law.
>
> **22** But the scripture hath concluded all under sin, that the
>   promise by faith of Jesus Christ might be given to them that believe.
>
> **23** But before faith came, we were kept under the law, shut
>   up unto the faith which should afterwards be revealed.
>
> **24** Wherefore the law was our schoolmaster to bring us unto
>   Christ, that we might be justified by faith.
>
> **25** But after that faith is come, we are no longer under a
>   schoolmaster.

From this, we see that the Law was the "schoolmaster" given to bring us unto Christ. In fact, the Law was given to show us how foolish it is to try and merit or otherwise deserve God's love and salvation. It's impossible. By inspecting ourselves in the light of the Law, we see that we are sinners and that we come short of the glory of God, however hard we try. We cannot be righteous by our own efforts. And so the Law brings us to Christ, the only solution to our sin.

Christianity is in this regard unique. In all religions, men thrive to be righteous by their own power and efforts in order to please God. By *accomplishing* the Law and dying for us, Jesus freed us from it, so we are not to try and deserve God's love and salvation, but accept his mercy and grace as a free gift, unrelated to all our efforts.

The Law being what drives us to Christ, we are not required to follow it anymore, since through the Holy Spirit, the Law is now written in our hearts, fulfilling the promise of Jeremiah 31:33:

> **33** But this shall be the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel; After those days, saith the LORD, I will put my law in their inward parts, and write it in their hearts; and will be their God, and they shall be my people.

In fact, Paul warned the Galatians against coming back unto the Law after having received the Spirit, and called them foolish for doing so (Galatians 3 again):

> **1** O foolish Galatians, who hath bewitched you, that ye should not obey
>   the truth, before whose eyes Jesus Christ hath been evidently set
>   forth, crucified among you?
>
> **2** This only would I learn of you, Received ye the Spirit by the works
>   of the law, or by the hearing of faith?
>
> **3** Are ye so foolish? having begun in the Spirit, are ye now made
>   perfect by the flesh?
>
> **4** Have ye suffered so many things in vain? if it be yet in vain.

Now as El'endia pointed out, James 2:26 tells us that faith without works is dead:

> **26** Just as the body is dead without breath, so also faith is dead without good works.

which expresses that a living faith will bear fruit, seens through good works, but does not mean we ought to make efforts to follow the Law of Moses, as pointed by Paul in Galatians.

Comment: +10 if I could. :D

Comment: If the law is in the heart, you would naturally obey it. `Not following` the law - if by this you meant disobeying the law, then the law is simply not in your heart

Answer (score 1):

In studying Scripture , we must be careful to avoid making category errors, assigning properties and attributes to a situation meant  to be assigned to a different situation. In 1 John, it says those born of the Spirit cannot  sin. But if we do sin, if we confess our sin, Christ is faithful  and will cleanse us of all unrighteousness. Obviously the writer is talking about different situations, different uses of the word sin.

What Law (Torah) does

There was no moral law in the Garden, so where there is no law, no transgression takes place. You could say Adam could commit murder and still not be guilty (a parallel seen in the situation of minors in modern society, who commit adult crimes: they have immunity). The only act capable of incurring death, separation from God was choosing to judge good and evil, be autonomous, like God, but a huge task, something they were not equipped  for. Still huge, BTW.

After the Fall, Adam was placed in a world where moral law existed and was enforced. Now there is no immunity. Even when men do not commit Adam's sin, choosing autonomy, they still suffer death, separation from God.  TRANSGRESSION has appeared.

The Law was given because of this transgression which leads to separation from God. Those who believed God requires moral rectitude (even without Torah, such as the righteous Gentiles) were given protective custody, (the pedagogos was the trusted family servant who ensured safety till shelter was reached, till Christ came). There was no separation from God for those who observed the law, but  there was also no provision for eternal life. Moral living, meeting the requirements of the Law, Torah, provides protection  from separation from God, both to Jew and Gentile alike, with or without the Torah. Torah was given because of the appearance of law, post Fall, which brings transgression into play.

Eternal living was only possible when Jesus came, who provided it, in addition to immunity.

Eternal life is the Garden life. Immunity from moral law, of which Torah is a subset (in moral law, even looking at a woman lustfully is sin, and divorce is not allowed. It's a superior law, the bar of which has been raised, as seen in the Sermon on the Mount).

You are not under the jurisdiction of the moral law, compliance is not required, it's penalties  blunted. You were once enslaved to it , not as in addicted, but rather coming under its whip. You can now commit adultery or do drugs with impunity , but that would lead to slavery, addiction. You would then come under God's wrath, explained as the termination of your opportunity to successfully serve God, and to thus receive eternal life in the world to come.

Why not instead be a slave to Christ, who has provided immunity, empowerment through the Holy Spirit leading to putting to death the sins  of the body through the Spirit leading to the privilege of participating in Christ's ministry, the ability to offer a perfected sacrifice.

The law to be obeyed then is the Royal Law, the Law of Liberty and Love, the law of doing the works God has given you to do, to confirm the Gospel  you share.

Comment: Do you have some textual justification for this interpretation, particularly regarding the assertion that there was no moral law before the fall? I would have assumed that any rule/requirement placed on any human would count as moral law (even if it differed from rules placed on other people later).

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do we have to obey the laws of the bible? If so, what laws?

Religious groups require obedience to some biblical laws if you want to continue as a member of that Church. These vary from Religion to religion. In order to join the early church a new "gentile" convert had to agree to abide by the Seven laws of Noah, even if he could not accept Judaism's "laws."

The Seven Laws of Noah were recognized by the United States Congress in the preamble to the 1991 bill that established Education Day in honor of the birthday of Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson, the leader of the Chabad movement:
*Whereas Congress recognizes the historical tradition of ethical values and principles which are the basis of civilized society and upon which our great Nation was founded; Whereas these ethical values and principles have been the bedrock of society from the dawn of civilization, when they were known as the Seven Noahide Laws.* [from wikipedia.]

Any "gentile" who lived these laws of Noah, was considered by the Hebrews to be equal to a High Priest in righteousness.

God does not demand that we obey any "laws," we are asked to love God above all else. The laws are rules given to "children" who do not yet have "the laws written on their hearts;" do not yet recognize "The Christ within them." 
Until that time they need a teacher who will explain what it means to love God. When you become mature in the Faith, and love God with all your heart, body, mind and soul, and have become "perfect" as Paul has said, you no longer need the teacher, as Paul has said.

You always have a choice whether to follow the rules or not. The rules are "natural laws," which if you try to break them have a consequence of their own. As Steven R. Covey said ( I have met him) in "The seven habits of highly effective people," *"When you pick up one end ot the stick, the other comes with it."*

The greatest gift that God gave to Adam was that of choice.  Whether you are willing to follow natural laws is your choice. A happy life ensues if you follow those that pertain to your life.

At the final judgement, Christ is going to ask you whether you have given water, food and clothes to His brethren. And whether you visited His Brethren when they were sick, or in prison (spiritual.) He is not going to ask you what Religion you follow or which laws you broke.

An Anglican scholar.

Comment: -1; This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. I made a mental leap here. I will have another go at it.

Comment: And so you know, you can add links to your posts by using the [link text](link address) combination; for example, [Seven Laws of Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahide_laws) becomes Seven Laws of Noah. This makes it easier to show (and check) references.

Answer (score 1):

Your salvation is a result of your belief in Jesus Christ.  What others may say or think is irrelevant.  We do not have to guess what law we are to keep; the immutable ten commandments. Three times in the book of Revelation  they are spoken of.

Revelation 12;17

And the dragon was wroth with the woman, and went to make war with the remnant of her seed, which keep the commandments of God and have the testimony of Jesus Christ.

Revelation 14;12

Here is the patience of the saints: here are they that keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus

Revelation 22;14

Blessed are they that do his commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may enter in through the gates into the city.

In our own strength,we cannot keep the commandments, no more than Paul could keep the law. But ; Romans 9;37  Nay, in all these things we are more than conquerors through him that loved us. Because we are saved, the Holy Spirit works through us for God's purpose.

Comment: Booo. Do you not know that some of God's commandments are applicable only in certain timeframes or contexts? Have a look at Acts 15:1-29, for an example. Or Acts 10, where Peter has a vision telling him it's okay to eat bacon (our New Covenant celebration food! :D). Not only that, but I like to point out to people that John actually **says** that Jesus "broke" the Sabbath! See John 5:16-18.

Comment: @Andrew John never said Jesus broke the Sabbath. John said according to the Pharisees Jesus broke the Sabbath to which Jesus answered "I am the Lord of the Sabbath day" meaning - the way I keep the Sabbath Holy is the correct way to keep it.

Comment: @OneFace "This was why the Jews were seeking all the more to kill him, because not only **was he breaking the Sabbath**, but he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God" (John 5:18).

Comment: @OneFace In fact I'll do you one better, okay? If "not only was he breaking the Sabbath" was not John saying that Jesus broke the Sabbath, then what was John saying in the exact same sentence when he said, "he was even calling God his own Father, making himself equal with God"? Would you dare to suggest that John was *not* saying that Jesus was calling God His Father?

Comment: That is the accusation Jews brought against Jesus. The situation in which the comment was made about Sabbath makes it clear beyond doubt that Jesus did not break the Sabbath except the misconceptions of Jews. KJV Mark 3
4 And he saith unto them, Is it lawful to do good on the sabbath days, or to do evil? to save life, or to kill? But they held their peace.

Comment: It was the Jews "tradition" that forbade them to do good on Sabbath. Not the commandments of God. That Jesus claimed God as His father is true. This is also one of the accusations Jews brought against Jesus. @Andrew it is noteworthy that they did not bring any of these as the major accusation against Jesus in the final trial to kill Him. Had it been a break in God's law, Jews would have brought it up 100%. It shows clearly that Christ as the Lord of Sabbath, kept it according to God's will.

Comment: @OneFace You don't know that they didn't bring it up, only that it wasn't written. They did bring up the most important charge of all.

Comment: @OneFace I'm not so sure about your claim that the Sabbath law wasn't against a man picking up his bed and walking on a Sabbath day. Take for instance: "Thus says the LORD: Take care for the sake of your lives, and do not bear a burden on the Sabbath day or bring it in by the gates of Jerusalem. And do not carry a burden out of your houses on the Sabbath or do any work, but keep the Sabbath day holy, as I commanded your fathers" (Jeremiah 17:21-22). Or perhaps how in Numbers 15:32-36, a man was found gathering sticks on a Sabbath and God commanded him to be stoned to death.

Comment: @OneFace There is a similar occurrence 2 chapters later: "Moses gave you circumcision (not that it is from Moses, but from the fathers), and you circumcise a man on the Sabbath. If on the Sabbath a man receives circumcision, so that the law of Moses may not be broken, are you angry with me because on the Sabbath I made a man's whole body well? Do not judge by appearances, but judge with right judgment'" (John 7:22-24). Note: His claim was not that circumcision didn't break it, but that some things take precedence. Jesus did break it in John 5; only, it was rightful to do so. That's the point.

Comment: It can't be considered breaking if it is rightful to do so. That is my point. Jesus plainly said KJV John 15:10 "If ye keep my commandments, ye shall abide in my love; **even as I have kept my Father's commandments**, and abide in his love." Jesus did not break the Sabbath. The Bible actually describes burdens in Nehemiah 13:15,19. It clearly identifies burdens as things that are involved with trade - corn and wine, wheat and barley, fish etc... Carrying your bed after waking up is not a burden - this is what Jesus wanted to teach the Jews.

Comment: @Andrew If Jesus had broken Sabbath, then it would have been definitely definitely brought up because breaking Sabbath is a clean and sure accusation by which any criminal can be condemned without any controversy, as Mosaic law clearly allows it. That it is not written simply shows that Jesus did not break it. In fact, they were struggling to find any witness at all that they had to make do with false witnesses. I can't agree that it would not have been written if such an unbreakable and sure charge was brought up against Jesus

Comment: Kindly take a look here: https://digitalcommons.andrews.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1027&context=jats for a research paper regarding this topic. I think we might be overloading the comment section.

Comment: @OneFace It is breaking the Sabbath though, and that's what He did. He didn't sin; He kept His Father's commandments. But He did so by breaking the Sabbath for the greater commandments. They take precedence. A good example of this sort of thing might be Phinehas: he "murdered" the man and the woman, but he did not sin, he was commended by God. Was he explicitly commanded to do what he did? No. Was there some law that said, "Thou shalt kill in this kind of situation."? No. The Law is meant to instruct, not to technically never ever be broken in any way.

Comment: @OneFace Are you blind, or out of your mind? It **was** brought up, by the leaders! And it **was** written, by John himself! I don't care what kind of "context" you think this passage has or doesn't have, and I'm not going to read a paper that dismisses what John clearly said. **The Bible says that Jesus broke the Sabbath.** The instant you say otherwise you are contradicting the Bible. (Seriously, go read it.) Overloading the comment section is fine because this is its purpose... If the mods don't like it they are the ones with the power to move it to chat.

Comment: 1John 3:4 Whosoever committeth sin transgresseth also the law: for sin is the transgression of the law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105113/discussion-between-one-face-and-andrew).

Answer (score 0):

Paul laid it out clearly the moral sins that lead to death. They are based on old testament commands. They are our fence lines on the road to life eternal.
Love is in the center of the road.

Riding the ditch is bumpy and dangerous.

Paul also added, Romans 7, You know by the law....a  woman is bound to her husband as long as he lives , but, then says, In Romans 7:4, the wife (figuratively) dies. "Ye are become dead to the law that ye should be married to another."       Christ died to free us from ..... Laws which are not sins unto death.

Comment: "Paul laid it out clearly the moral sins that lead to death." Where?