# Does Matthew 5:38-40 mean we have to remain pacifist?

Tags: life-of-jesus, matthew, sermon-on-the-mount, pacifism

In Matthew 5:38-40 Jesus Christ tells us that if someone hit you on the right check that you the other check to him also, does this means as Christians that we are supposed to remain pacifist and that we are not allowed to fight back if somebody attempts to attack us?

Because in Matthew 5:38-40 Christ says:

> 38 Ye have heard that it hath been said, An eye for an eye, and a
> tooth for a tooth:
>
> 39 But I say unto you, That ye resist not evil: but whosoever shall
> smite thee on thy right cheek, turn to him the other also.
>
> 40 And if any man will sue thee at the law, and take away thy coat,
> let him have thy cloak also.

Comment: I think Jesus is teaching us a lesson on self-control, about not letting the sin and evil of others get the best of us. It's so easy to get carried away when people hurt you, and you want to get back at them so badly, you let your anger get the best of you. I think Jesus is telling us not to do that. Essentially, He's saying this; "don't let the actions of others affect you such that you are driven to take revenge." He's not telling us that self-defence is off-limits. If someone attacks you, and you have no choice *but* to fight back, then you should.

Comment: Jesus exhorts that, for a slap on the face, one is to turn the other cheek. Paul does not expect a _more serious assault_ to be so tolerated, 2 Corinthians 11:20, a 'striking of the face'.

Comment: I think you'll find a more complete question and answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/what-is-the-biblical-and-historical-basis-for-christian-pacifism