# Does the Bible allow us to protect our selves

Tags: killing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do we as Christians draw the line on self-defense?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/when-do-we-as-christians-draw-the-line-on-self-defense)

I am referring to turning the other cheek. With all the violence going on I am wondering if we can protect our selves or does the turn the other cheek mean we should just let someone harm us?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I don't want to discourage your participation, but this question has been asked before (in a slightly different way). Also, this is more of a "Pastoral Advice" question than a question about Christianity. I'd recommend checking out the [FAQ] for more of an understanding of what the site is meant for.  "Does the Bible say XXXXXXX" questions are specifically mentioned as not a good fit for the site.  If you have questions, feel free to ask in chat.

Comment: See also: [Christian response(s) to disaster survival, or Christian self-defense](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3078)